# Issue with preloading assets to browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, xmlhttprequest, fetch

I have a Nodejs App running on background and I have this code in frontend ( here it's simplified for you ) to **preload** videos , audios , etc ... to **blobs** like this:

```
   function preloadOne(url, done) {
      const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhrs.push(xhr);
      xhr.open('GET', url, true);
      xhr.responseType = 'blob';
      xhr.onprogress = event => {
        if (!event.lengthComputable) return false;
        let item = this.getItemByUrl(event.target.responseURL);
        item.completion = parseInt((event.loaded / event.total) * 100);
        item.downloaded = event.loaded;
        item.total = event.total;
        this.updateProgressBar(item);
      };
      xhr.onload = event => {
        let type = event.target.response.type;
        let blob = new Blob([event.target.response], {
          type: type
        });
        let url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        let responseURL = event.target.responseURL;
        let item = this.getItemByUrl(responseURL);
        item.blobUrl = url;
        item.fileName = responseURL.substring(responseURL.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        item.type = type;
        item.size = blob.size;
        done(item);
      };
      xhr.onerror = event => {}
      xhr.send();
    }
```

Everything is going fine until I reach 32mb transferred then the transfer gets really slow and for the next 10 mb to load I need more time than what I needed to reach 30MBs!!??

Sometimes and not all the times I get this error for loading a video too:

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Here you can see the end of the fast part of the preloading where suddenly everything gets slow:

[image]

Any suggestions why this is happening and how to fix this is a good point to start and debug this and it's really appreciated ...

For me it seems something get's full after 30 MBs :)

**UPDATE: it a more complete version of the code to have a look if you need it:**

```js
async function Preloading() {

    preloadedPercent = 0;
    setTimeout(() => startBlink(), 1500);
    (function (global, factory) {
        typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module !== 'undefined' ? module.exports = factory() :
        typeof definer === 'function' && definer.amd ? definer(factory) :
        (global.Preload = factory());
    }(this, (function () { 

    'use strict';

    function preloadOne(url, done) {
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', url, true);
        xhr.responseType = 'blob';
        xhr.onprogress = event => {
            if(!event.lengthComputable) return false
            let item = this.getItemByUrl(event.target.responseURL);
            item.completion = parseInt((event.loaded / event.total) * 100);
            item.downloaded = event.loaded;
            item.total = event.total;
            this.updateProgressBar(item);
        };
        xhr.onload = event => {
            let type = event.target.response.type;
            let blob = new Blob([event.target.response], { type: type });
            let url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            let responseURL = event.target.responseURL;
            let item = this.getItemByUrl(responseURL);
            item.blobUrl = url;
            item.fileName = responseURL.substring(responseURL.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
            item.type = type;
            item.size = blob.size;
            done(item);
        };
      
        xhr.onerror = event => {
            console.log('Error Happend in Preloading');
            reload();
        };
        xhr.send();
    }

    function updateProgressBar(item) {
        var sumCompletion = 0;
        var maxCompletion = this.status.length * 100;
        for(var itemStatus of this.status) {
            if(itemStatus.completion) {
                sumCompletion += itemStatus.completion;
            }
        }
        var totalCompletion = parseInt((sumCompletion / maxCompletion) * 100);
        if(!isNaN(totalCompletion)) {
            this.onprogress({
                progress: totalCompletion,
                item: item
            });
        }
    }

    function getItemByUrl(rawUrl) {
        for (var item of this.status) {
            if (item.url == rawUrl) return item
        }
    }

    function fetch(list) {  
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.loaded = list.length;
            for (let item of list) {
                this.status.push({ url: item });
                this.preloadOne(item, item => {
                    this.onfetched(item);
                    this.loaded--;
                    if (this.loaded == 0) {
                      this.oncomplete(this.status);
                      resolve(this.status);
                    }
                });
            }
        })
    }

    function Preload() {
        return {
            status: [],
            loaded: false,
            onprogress: () => {},
            oncomplete: () => {},
            onfetched: () => {},
            fetch,
            updateProgressBar,
            preloadOne,
            getItemByUrl
        }
    }

    return Preload;

    })));

    const preload = Preload();
    preload.fetch(preloadingData.preloadURLs).then(items => {});
    preload.oncomplete = items => {
        Media = generateMedia(items);
        Blobs = generateBlobs(items);
        sfx = getSfx();
        preloadProgress(100, true); 
        preloadingData = null;
    }
    preload.onprogress = event => { preloadProgress(event.progress); }
    preload.onfetched = item => {} 
}

function preloadProgress(value, done) {
    if(value > preloadedPercent || done) {
        preloadedPercent = value;
        checkRestart = 0;
        checkLatency(value);
        progressBar(value, done);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you expect `this` to refer to inside the xhr "progress" callback? And what does that `getItemByUrl()` function do?

Comment: This whole function and its helper functions which is not included in the above code creates a blob url in the browsers memory so it technically preload the video to be played without lags in the browser. I will put a complete version of the code if you want ..

Comment: So `preloadOne()` is a method on a larger object? Most importantly, what does `getItemByUrl()` do?

Comment: I put the long version of the code in a update please have a look at `getItemByUrl` function there...

Comment: I'm not sure *exactly* what's going on, but it looks like your code starts a lot of concurrent xhr requests. Browsers will only open a certain maximum number of TCP connections for HTTP requests; once that limit is reached, the browser waits for earlier requests to finish.

Comment: So you mean if I request a video and wait when it's finish request the other one this slowing down not occur ?

Comment: Although it's only 14 videos each 2 - 10 mbs